# error connection to service named rtcreportingd using AVPlayer on MacOS

Tags: macos, avplayer, avplayerview

I have a very simply MacOS app where I am trying to use AVPlayerView/AVPlayer on MacOS to play a small mp4 from a remote url.

I constantly get errors about a connection to service com.apple.rtcreportingd.
Here's a full log of the errors I get:

```
2019-05-19 12:06:47.286932-0700 MyApp[5849:39995] startConfigurationWithCompletionHandler: Failed to get remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd}
2019-05-19 12:06:47.287081-0700 MyApp[5849:39995] startConfigurationWithCompletionHandler: Failed to get remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd}
2019-05-19 12:06:47.392044-0700 MyApp[5849:40033] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C2.1:2][0x10141c0a0] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-05-19 12:06:47.392105-0700 MyApp[5849:40033] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C2.1:2][0x10141c0a0] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-05-19 12:06:47.392269-0700 MyApp[5849:40033] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
2019-05-19 12:06:47.392285-0700 MyApp[5849:40033] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
2019-05-19 12:06:47.622099-0700 MyApp[5849:39997] sendMessageWithDictionary: Failed to get remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd}
2019-05-19 12:06:47.639382-0700 MyApp[5849:39997] sendMessageWithDictionary: Failed to get remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd}
2019-05-19 12:06:48.123992-0700 MyApp[5849:40031] sendMessageWithDictionary: Failed to get remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd}
2019-05-19 12:06:48.129544-0700 MyApp[5849:40029] sendMessageWithDictionary: Failed to get remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd}
```

The playback seems to be working ok, but still I'd like to know how to make it stop. It's hiding any other debug message I am printing out.

The code to setup the AVPlayer is pretty straightforward. I have a NSCollectionViewItem which has an AVPlayerView inside of it.
Then, I set the `.player` property on the view using something like this:

```swift
if let previewUrl = URL(string: "https://url-to-an-mp4") {
    playerView?.player = AVPlayer(url: previewUrl)
}
```

I googled extensively, there's not much info about rtcreportingd out there.

Comment: I am seeing this also with AVPlayer even though everything else seems to be working correctly. Did you ever figure out a way to silence it?

Comment: have the same issue with AVPlayer, cant silent those comments. any idea?

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode, open: **Product** > **Scheme** > **Edit Scheme**

Under *Environment Variables* set `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` to `disable`